# android app dev screen size support

Tags: android, android-layout, view, android-gui

I've read [Android Multiple Screen Support](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) and watch youtube tutorials regarding supporting different sizes of screen resolutions for android app.

What they commonly do is to create multiple drawable-xxxxx folders and layout-xxxxx folders and manually edit the GUIs, adjusting the images to their preferences. Atleast 4 copies of the original is manually made. I'm currently starting my android game app right now, what if I want to support multiple screen resolutions? Do I really need to manually create 4 other copies of my game? For instance I'm making a clone of Flappy Bird, do I need to re-engineer 4 copies of it to fit multiple screen sizes? Adjusting positions, sizes, and recalculating computations to fit the animations and such? Or is there an easy way out there? I've been searching and watching videos about screen supports, but all points to that multiple folders/xml/drawables.

Comment: If you are writing a game, follow the instructions from the game engine or framework that you are using.

Comment: What do you mean by this? What I'm currently doing is coding menu using android studio. I don't think I'm using any game engine/framework

Comment: Then perhaps you may wish to consider using an existing [2D game engine](http://android-arsenal.com/tag/1) or framework. The documentation is for more traditional apps; games have their own approaches towards solving problems like screen sizes and densities.

Comment: Then I shouldn't use android studio/eclipse and instead use Pure2D for instance? Something like that?

Comment: Some of the game engines will still have you use a traditional IDE. Others will have their own tools. That varies. My point is that AFAIK most game developers are starting from "I am writing a game", not from "I am writing an Android app". Or, to put it another way, if I were going to write a game, I would be using some existing engines/frameworks that were optimized for writing a game.